# How do you beat the Choices, Choices challenge in Hero Academy?

Tags: hero-academy

I am thoroughly stumped on the Choices, Choices Dark Elves challenge.  How can I beat this one?  It seems like a job for the void monk, but he can't quite finish them off.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are correct about Void Monk.  The trick is to give him a boost, through the Assault Boost square.  Take out the Cleric with the Necromancer, then move the Void Monk to the Assault Boost square and take out the other three units.

Comment: Ah, thanks.  I thought i'd tried that, but apparently i hadn't quite.

Comment: @Nathan - No problem.  Glad to help.

Comment: When I saw this answer, I thought "but I tried that!" then I realized what I was missing--I didn't know you could walk right THROUGH other characters!